# Replace text in several stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have to replace text pointing to an object to point into another object for different stored procedures. I have to modify the text within them and they're several, so scripting them as alter and then changing the text is not ideal.

I was able to identify the `SP` I need to change via a query:

```
--Search in Stored Procedure Only
SELECT DISTINCT 
    OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID), 
    OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID)
FROM sys.Procedures
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%' + 'stringToSearch' + '%';

GO
```

I'm struggling about how to do the replace of the text for them.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This would be better suited to do in your database project in SSDT. Then you can find, and replace, the needed values, and then deploy your updated procedures.

Comment: it makes sense, I'll try with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can generate a script from your database
(right click on your database--> tasks--> generate script--> select just your procedures)
and then open it in the SSMS, then press cntrl+f, and then replace your specific text

Comment: This is a good solution, I was thinking it on ways of doing via script, but this actually makes sense and takes advantage of the tool. thank you.